# Try to run a Xcode project but only got error: "clang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-check'"

Tags: c++, xcode

I am learning stanford CS 106b and I downloaded the pathfinder starter file from here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/

However, this starter file cannot be executed on my latest Xcode.  The errors are as follows:

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-check'
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I googled this error, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: How is `clang` being executed? `clang` in Xcode, to my knowledge, doesn't currently support AddressSanizer (which I think is what the `stack-check` flag is for.) If `clang` is being run from a script, remove that flag and try re-running. Post fuller output to a place like pastebin and we can take a look.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/soj5b7bom6gv9o5/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202015-03-25%2002.17.49%20PM.png?dl=0   This is the output from my Xcode. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the project has `-fstack-check` set under `OTHER_CFLAGS`. Boo. Doing a project-wide search (with cmd-shift-f) and searching for "stack-check" will show you where it's set. Here's a screen capture of that: http://cl.ly/2T2E2h161p0B (the bottom right corner shows keyboard entry)

Comment: There are many other build problems with this particular Xcode project, however. I used to do build engineering at Apple, and this project looks like it needs a lot of love to build and link successfully.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @cbowns . I followed your screen capture, however, only got even more errors: https://www.dropbox.com/s/enos9r3t8f4ka7x/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202015-03-25%2008.59.03%20PM.png?dl=0  Actually I tried what you did before. I am now using Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e) I think maybe it's because the version has been updated. I also tried Xcode 5.1 but still cannot execute it.

Comment: Yeah, the errors it prints out are quite hairy. I think the project itself is very poorly structured and/or has external dependencies they didn't document.